# Can't run yum update or install on cloudlinux 8.6 (Invalid version flag: if)

Tags: yum, upgrade

I can't run `yum update`. When I try, I get this:

```
--> Processing Dependency: python3-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-18.el7 for package: python3-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64 -
--> Package python3-pycparser.noarch 0:2.14-14.el8 will be installed -
--> Package readline.x86_64 0:6.2-11.el7 will be updated 
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.6()(64bit) for package: alt-sqlite-3.26.0-1.1.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.6()(64bit) for package: cpanel-sqlite-3.32.3-1.cp1198.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.6()(64bit) for package: python-libs-2.7.5-91.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.6()(64bit) for package: alt-php-internal-cli-7.4.22-2.el7.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.6()(64bit) for package: jetlftp-4.9.1.1-1.x86_64 -
--> Package redhat-rpm-config.noarch 0:129-1.el8.alma will be installed Error: Invalid version flag: if
```

CloudLinux release: 8.6

Comment: Could you please format the code properly? Right now it's a 6km long string, so it's hard to discern what is what.

Comment: Do you get the same error when running `dnf update`?

Comment: `-bash: dnf: command not found`

Comment: Something has gone terribly wrong with your system. Cloud Linux 8.6 ships with `dnf` as the *only* available package manager; `/usr/bin/yum` is  a symlink to `dnf`. Can you tell us more about the history of this system?

Comment: Something has gone terribly wrong with your system. Cloud Linux 8.6 ships with `dnf` as the *only* available package manager; `/usr/bin/yum` is  a symlink to `dnf`. Can you tell us more about the history of this system?

Comment: Firstly it was Centos 7, then Almalinux and then cloudlinux

Comment: The error you posted looks to have packages tagged with `.el7` and `.el8` in addition to `.cloudlinux` and `.alma` which could indicate that one of the upgrades did not go through properly and/or you did not remove the older repositories.  Please post the output of `rpm -q rpm` and `rpm -qa | grep release` to help determine what may have failed.

Comment: rpm -q rpm output  `rpm-4.11.3-48.el7_9.x86_64` and rpm -qa | grep release output 
`remi-release-7.9-3.el7.remi.noarch

percona-release-1.0-27.noarch

cpanel-trigger-os-release-1.2-1.cp1198.noarch
epel-release-7-14.noarch
rpmfusion-free-release-7-4.noarch
elevate-release-1.0-1.el7.noarch
cloudlinux-release-8.6-1.el8.x86_64
nodesource-release-el7-1.noarch
cloudlinux-ea4-release-1-7.el8.noarch`

Comment: Someone can help me to fix this?